# Troubleshooting compiler errors with many nested #include statements

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017, devenv

The code I work with for my career is written in C++ and built with a DevEnv wrap (1.61) for Visual Studio 15.

Much of the work is configuring structs through a series of `#include` statements that end up very nested, for example:

```
//ObjRTC.h
struct OBJ_RTC
{
    OBJ_SETTINGS    settings;
    OBJ_ESTOPS      emergencyStops[maxEstops];
    OBJ_MACHINES    machines[maxMachines];
    OBJ_FOO         bar[maxFooBars];
};
```

.

```
//ObjMachines.h
struct OBJ_MACHINES
{
    bool    inUse;
    INPUTS  inputDevices[maxInputDevices];
    OUTPUTS outputDevices[maxOutputDevices];
};
```

Those structs are further defined in other files, and we begin declaring the values in 'def' files.

```
// DefRTC.h
OBJ_RTC RealTimeController = {
    #include "DefSettings.h"
    #include "DefEstops.h"
    #include "DefMachines.h"
    #include "DefFoo.h"
};
```

.

```
// DefMachines.h
{
    {
        true,
        { /* list of inputs */ },
        { /* list of outputs */ },
    },
    {
        true,
        { /* list of inputs */ },
        { /* list of outputs */ },
    },
    {
        true,
        { /* list of inputs */ },
        { /* list of outputs */ },
    },
},
```

If there is a syntax issue in the declaration files, during compilation it will often only ever get reported as coming from the last line of `DefRTC.h`.

I know I could start copying the files and pasting over the `#include` lines, which I have done while trying to resolve an issue (a value of type `INPUT` configured in place of an `OUTPUT`)

Is there a way to have the compiler report where the syntax error came from with respect to file being `#included`?

Comment: Where does the data for these includes come from? Maybe it would be better to write import util that will generate include files?

Comment: Presumably the missing semicolons are actually present in the real code?

Comment: Wow, truly hideous.  Ups the ante for "The Preprocessor is Evil", congrats!

Comment: Ah, corrected the missing semicolons.
The declarations and definitions for all the structs are in header files. The source files loop through the structs to perform some initialization (sometimes creating objects)

Comment: The problem has nothing to do with nested #include directives. It pertains to nested {{{}}} structures. If you forgot one of the internal braces, the compiler often has no way of knowing that until the very end of the nested structure, and even then, no way of knowing which of the braces is forgotten.

Comment: True, however if I make a mistake such as the wrong type where the compiler shows an error C2440: 'initializing': cannot convert from 'FOO' to 'BAR' then it reports the error as the last line of DefRTC.h rather than the Defxxx.h file where the mistake was made

Comment: Missing curly braces are actually generally easier to find the issue because they report in the file the mistake occurred, or sometimes in the next file in the structure depending on what was missing

Comment: Clang advertises itself to do this kind of error reporting better.  If you use VS2015 and up then just change the toolset of the project.

Answer (score 0):

You can preprocess the .c file which gives compiler errors and compile that preprocessed file.
Then the error/warning will always refer to a line in that file.
You can then identify the original file from which the lines are coming, by inserting bookmarks which survive preprocessing. The bookmarks basically just note the file name in one of the first lines of each file.
How to make a preprocessor-surviving bookmark (because comments and preprocess defines are lost of course) ?

Write a typedef, it does not consume any resources (apart from namespace useage)
and it is still present for human eyes reading proprocessed files:

```
typedef int BookmarkFilename1_h_Start;
```

For added convenience in navigation, add another bookmark at the end of each header:

```
typedef int BookmarkFilename1_h_End;
```

Then, in order to find the line number in the header (if it is very long), subtract line number of bookmark (in preprocessed file) from line number of error in pp-file. Then add line number of bookmark in original header.
Apart from useages of multiline macros (with `\` continuation), this should give you filename and original line number.

In case your toolchain/buildenvironment complains about use of `int`, replace it with any other accepted already visible type.

For focused identification of suspected lines, you can add bookmarks in nearby lines, close to the suspects. Just make sure that you are suitably out of scope of anything, i.e. in a place where making a typedef is no problem.

Comment: MSVC is rumored not to preprocess in a way that the result can be compiled. It might take some research how to achieve that. (gcc and clang are rumored to preprocess compilably). I do not want to make this part of the answer, because of only having heard rumors and not wanting to blackpaint any compiler maker. Comments on this are welcome.